# Is there a templating language similar to Razor for Java Spring web applications?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc, template-engine, templating

I'm in love with razor templates in .NET MVC 3. Is there anything close for java?

I'd be looking for something where I could avoid using JSTL tags and instead do something like this:

```
<c:if test=${bla}>
   <span>my html</span>
</c:if>
```

and instead do

```
@if(bla)
{
  <span>my html</span>
}
```

I'm assuming there must be similar

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd like to introduce my work: [Rythm template engine](http://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm), a lightweight and super fast template engine in Java using the [**Razor**](http://razorengine.codeplex.com) like syntax. Rythm has rich features and supports page layout/inheritance, customized tags (either in template or java class), dynamic reload at dev mode and much more. The [benchmark](http://rythmengine.com/document/feature) shows Rythm is 2 to 3 times faster than [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine) on a normal page!

The API is simple:

1. render with inline string:

   `String output = Rythm.render("@args String who;hello @who!", "world");`
2. render with template file:

   `String output = Rythm.render("hello.txt", "world");`

A brief introduction to Rythm: http://software-lgl.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/rythm-easy-to-use-high-performance-java.html

**Updates 20120701**

The latest version introduced a feature called "[String Interpolation Mode](http://www.playframework.org/modules/rythm-1.0.0-20120630/string_interpolation)", which enable you to do very lightweight string interpolation like follows:

```
String result = Rythm.render("hello @who!", "world");
```

A **full feature demonstration** is hosted on GAE: http://play-rythm-demo.appspot.com/

**Updates 20130406**

A rythm fiddle web site is online now, and you can use it to learn Rythm syntax. Check it out at http://fiddle.rythmengine.org

**Updates 20130513**

- package name changed from `com.greenlaw110.rythm` to
  `org.rythmengine`, the maven group id changed accordingly
- Checkout the new project website: http://rythmengine.org

Comment: Rythm 1.0.0-RC1 released. With lots of some fantastic features. What about cache a unescaped tag result and assign it to a variable for later use like `@myTag(...).cache("3mn").raw().assign("myTagResult") ... @myTagResult.escape("html")`. Check more on http://software-lgl.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/playrythm-100-rc1-released.html

Comment: looks like your product is no longer being actively maintained (judging by the lack of activity on github)?

Comment: I appreciate your observation. There are few reasons: 1. Rythm is pretty mature and stable and I am still using it in many projects with great success; 2. My focus has shifted to http://github.com/actframework/actframework since 2014, and yes Rythm is the default templating solution in that MVC stack; 3. I need maintainer to join me on Rythm and other open source projects...

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there is none that looks and behaves quite like Razor in that Java world.

From what I can understand, the templating engine in Razor does not only parse the "placeholders" in the static text, like `#xxx` in Velocity or `${xxx}` in JSP.

Instead the `@` symbol in Razor acts as a toggle for switching to the hosting language parser (VB and C# in case of Razor), recognizing full syntax of the element immediately following the `@` sign. This allowes Razor to recognize both names of objects passed to the engine as well as syntactic structures like for loops and conditionals.

This opens up the full power of the hosting language to te Razor templates, which can be a dangerous thing in wrong hands...

Most of the templating engines in the Java side of the world have conciously chosen to strictly separate business logic from templating concerns and thus have very limited or no support for dynamic features like looping or conditionals in their template "languages", opting for declarative style over dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

Spring supports a number of templating languages:

- [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) (as mentioned in another answer)
- [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)
- Good ole' JSP, which if you use [taglibs](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/reference/docs/index.html) and [EL (Expression Language)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) is basically a template engine

For more reading on how to integrate with Spring, see [this page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html).

Additionally, there's [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/), which while not referenced in the official Spring documentation, [can be used](http://ca.rroll.net/2009/06/18/using-stringtemplate-as-the-view-engine-for-your-spring-mvc-application/) as a Spring template engine.

And if you *really* want to go wild, [here's a page](http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines) with about a bazillion other template engines.

Comment: This is the best answer, though none of these have the same razor style intelligent code vs html parsing that make it such a joy to use.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [twirl](https://github.com/spray/twirl), the Play framework template engine separated from the framework.

Example:

```
@if(items.isEmpty) {
  <h1>Nothing to display</h1>
} else {
  <h1>@items.size items!</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try having a look at velocity (http://velocity.apache.org)